# Strange error with calculator applet in java

Tags: java, applet, calculator

I'm making a calculator applet and have implemented it in the way most work, where if you have more than one operator the calculator evaluates what you've done so far, for example "4+4+4 = " will display 8 after the second + is hit, then 12 once enter is.

I'm running into a weird error when I do double digit numbers though, such as "12+12+12", it will display 24 after the second + is hit, but then I hit 1, then 2, and the 1 will disappear and the 2 will be registered as what is being added, making the expression 26 rather than 36.

I'm including some code below, one shows my evaluate method and the other shows my method for when the + is hit, I hope this is enough info. opCounter checks to see if there is more than 1 operand, if there is then it calls the eval function immediately to do the first addition/subtraction/etc.

I've been trying to figure out what's calling this problem for a while and can't manage to. f1 keeps track of one float and f2 keeps track of the other. tf is the text frame.

```
if(arg0.getSource()==bplus){

        if(parentheses == false){
        opCounter++;

        if(opCounter < 2){
            f1 = Float.parseFloat(tf.getText());
            tf.setText(""); 
        }else{
            eval();
        }
        operator= 1;    

        }else{
                tf.setText(tf.getText() + "+");
                parenthArg += "+";
                opCounter--;
        }


    }

public void eval(){

    if(parentheses == false){

    f2 = Float.parseFloat(tf.getText());

    if(operator == 1){
        tf.setText(Float.toString(f1+f2));
        f1 = f1+f2;
    }
    if(operator == 2){
        tf.setText(Float.toString(f1-f2));
        f1 = f1-f2;
    }
    if(operator == 3){
        tf.setText(Float.toString(f1*f2));
        f1 = f1*f2;
    }
    if(operator == 4){
        tf.setText(Float.toString(f1/f2));
        f1 = f1/f2;
    }


    operator = 0;
    System.out.println("f1: " + f1);
    System.out.println("f2: " + f2);

}
```

Comment: Sorry, I've been trying to debug for the past 2 hours and this is the only bug I have left in my program. Just can't seem to understand why it's only accepting 1 of the digits rather than both of them after there is more than 1 operator.

Comment: There's really not enough information here. You have a lot of global variables like "operator", "arg0", and "parnetheses" which are not defined in what you gave. Though Paul is right, this is just math. Use a debugging tool and step through each line of code until you figure out what the problem is.

Comment: My first impression is that there's an issue when grabbing the String from the text field. "4+4+4" is 5 characters long. "12+12" is 5 characters long as well, and then you have problems when you add stuff after that. You shouldn't get your float value from the text field. Just store all number values internally and display a copy in the text field.

Comment: it's not just math, it's an issue on grabbing 2 digits after there has already been an operator and i'm not sure why it only grabs 1. i'm not sure if i can store all the numbers internally since a user can click 1, 2 and that would need to be 12, either way it needs to be put into a string and then put into a float

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code?